# Android: SugarORM unable to extract requested data

Tags: android, database, android-listview, sugarorm

I am using SugarORM for managing database.

```
public class ExerciseDB extends SugarRecord 
{
    @Column(name = "ex_recordId", unique = true, notNull = true)
    private String ex_recordId;
    private String ex_group;
    private String ex_name;    
    private int ex_cal;

    public ExerciseDB()
    {
    }

    public ExerciseDB(String ex_recordId, String ex_group, String ex_name, int ex_cal) 
    {
        this.ex_recordId = ex_recordId;
        this.ex_group = ex_group;
        this.ex_name = ex_name;
        this.ex_cal = ex_cal;
    }
```

and then has loaded default transactions to the ExerciseDB, as follows:

```
ExerciseDB e1= new ExerciseDB("ex1", "Group1", "aaa", 190); save(e1);
ExerciseDB e2= new ExerciseDB("ex2", "Group1", "bbb", 180); save(e2);
```

### Question:

I would like to list out requested conditions of transactions to a listview.

While I know that if retrieving ALL entries can be done as follows:

```
List<ExerciseDB> Ex_db_record = null;
Ex_db_record = Select.from(ExerciseDB.class).orderBy("ex_recordId").list();
```

How could I get a list of, for example, only Group1 record and list by order of `ex_recordId`?
I have tried

```
Ex_db_record = ExerciseDB.find(ExerciseDB.class, "ex_group = ?", groupping);
```

but it gives out error as follows:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ex_group (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Ex_Records WHERE ex_group = ?
```

Comment: Quite an old post, but the solution to the issue is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647446/sugar-orm-for-android-cant-find-my-collumn-name/30192363#30192363

Answer (score -1):

You probably added ex_group later to the class, so try upgrading the Sugar DB version in your manifest file. It will look like this:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="VERSION"
            android:value="1" />
```

Update `android:value` to a higher version. Say `2`, in my case.