# Sugar ORM for Android cant find my column name

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

Well I'm trying to select all entities where `entitie_id = *some id*`

I do this with this rule:

```
List<NodeSugar> nodesugars = NodeSugar.find(NodeSugar.class, "entitie_id = ? ", String.valueOf(nodeid));
```

I know I should get some results back and I get an error.
this error:

```
E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column: entitie_id
```

I know the column exists because I can set it in a different part of code.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the Java name of the field you're trying to query by?

Answer (score 35):

You should be able to query with "entitieid".

Sugar ORM does some conversion when it creates the columns in the tables. Here is a basic example:

```
String firstName; //creates column first_name
int entitie_id;   //creates column entitieid
```

The documentation only specifies the conversion from camel case to underscore separation. I had to figure the other one out.

Comment: I just ask myself.. WHY?!

Comment: Great finding Tyler

Comment: This is still helpful. But idk why they implemented such conversion..
Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

You can use NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault() to wrap column names when building queries.  Try:

```
List<NodeSugar> nodesugars = NodeSugar.find(NodeSugar.class, NamingHelper.toSQLNameDefault("entitie_id") + " = ? ", String.valueOf(nodeid));
```

NamingHelper is used in the Sugar ORM library to create tables and column names:

https://github.com/satyan/sugar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/orm/helper/NamingHelper.java

Answer (score 0):

SugarORM currently uses `toSQLName()` method of the `StringUtil` class to generate names for columns
For example in your case:

```
List<NodeSugar> nodesugars = NodeSugar.find(NodeSugar.class, StringUtil.toSQLName("entitie_id")+" = ? ", String.valueOf(nodeid));
```

The other and neat way to do it would be to use the Select class:

```
List<NodeSugar> nodesugars = Select.from(NodeSugar.class).where(Condition.prop(StringUtil.toSQLName("entitie_id")).eq(nodeid)).list();
```

https://satyan.github.io/sugar/query.html